# Oracle Apex: Update selective columns based on column range

Tags: oracle, date, range, oracle-apex

I have columns as 001,002,003 till 254. want to update columns based on start date and end date range. Let's say I have selected start date as 01 Jan and end date as 10 Jan, then table columns 001-010 should get updated with user id, rest columns will be as it is.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Show examples of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Probably with multiple cases

```
   UPDATE YourTable 
   SET 001 = CASE WHEN 2017-01-01 BETWEEN startRange AND endRange
                  THEN newValue
                  ELSE 001
             END,
      002 = CASE WHEN 2017-01-02 BETWEEN startRange AND endRange
                  THEN newValue
                  ELSE 002
             END,
      ....
      xxx = CASE WHEN 2017-0x-0x BETWEEN startRange AND endRange
                  THEN newValue
                  ELSE xxx
             END,
```